# Laravel 10 Too many redirects when control a user roles

Tags: laravel, authentication, user-roles

Hello everyone when I control the admin users role I taking this error and I don't handle it

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{

```
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
    If(!$userRoles->contains('admin')){
        return  redirect(route('admin.login'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aytvZ.png)

Comment: if he's not an admin redirect to other page like forbidden or home page not to admin login page it makes none sense

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are getting many redirects because when you check the `$userRoles` you redirect it to `admin.login` route without logout the user , you need to logout the user first and then redirect it back to `admin.login`. I think you

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response {
   $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
    If(!$userRoles->contains('admin')){
        Auth::logout();
        return  redirect(route('admin.login'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```